# How to catch child window button click

Tags: jquery

I can't add code to the child window, so I have to catch event from parent window

```
$('#go').click(function(e) {
    win = window.open('http://google.com', 'test', 'width=800, height=600');

    $(win).load(function() {
        $(this).contents().find('button#gbqfba').click(function(){
            console.log('Child window click');
        });
    });        
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: If the child window part of your site? If not, you cannot do this because the browser blocks XSS.

Comment: It's not possible across domains i think, because of security... if not, you could do some very bad things.